# How should i design pagination component with async in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, pagination

How should i design javascript pagination component by async?
I want to synchronized http request/respone.
Because the pagination component must need total data count to figure out page count when component was created and initialized(like in constructer).
So the total data count is in my web server(or db) so i http requested total data count. But it was async api, so the code will not blocked when i request total data count to server. It must be blocked and dispose with synchronize.(because if component can't know total data count, then it can't initialized.
Below is my component code.

```
function ComponentPagination(paginationAreaID, pageViewDataCount , 
getTotalDataCountApiUrl)
{
this.OnUpdatePagingCallBack = null;

//div
var paginationArea = document.getElementById(paginationAreaID);
paginationArea.classList.add("component-pagination-area");

//prev button
var prevBtn = document.createElement("a");
prevBtn.textContent = "Prev";
paginationArea.appendChild(prevBtn);

//page buttons
var totalDataCount = getTotalDataCount();
if (totalDataCount == null) //If error occur
    totalDataCount = 0;

var pageCount = (totalDataCount / pageViewDataCount);

for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i) {
    var pageBtn = document.createElement("a");
    pageBtn.textContent = (i + 1) + "";
    pageBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

        if (this.OnUpdatePagingCallBack == null) {
            console.log("[Component Pagination Error] You must register 
                update paging callback function!");
            return;

        }

        var curClickedPage = event.target.textContent
        axios.get(getTotalDataCountApiUrl)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("[Component Pagination Error] " + error);
            });

    }.bind(this));

    paginationArea.appendChild(pageBtn);
}

//Next Button
var nextBtn = document.createElement("a");
nextBtn.textContent = "Next"
paginationArea.appendChild(nextBtn);

/* Private Function */
function getTotalDataCount()
{

    this.totalDataCount = 0; 
    axios.get('/API/TestAPI/GetTotalFileCount') //hard coded for test
        .then(function (response) {
            this.totalDataCount = response.data;
        }.bind(this))   
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("[Component Pagination Error] " + error);
        });


    return this.totalDataCount;
}

/* Call Back */
this.registerUpdatePagingCallBack = function(onUpdatePagingMethod)
{
    if (typeof onUpdatePagingMethod != "function")
    {
        console.log("[Component Pagination Error] You must pass only function 
         to registerUpdatePagingCallBack method's parameter");
        return;
    }
    this.OnUpdatePagingCallBack = onUpdatePagingMethod;

}
}
```

And then i use this like below in window.onload = function().

```
 var fileListPaginationer = new ComponentPagination("blocked-file-view-
 pagination-area", 10, "/API/TestAPI/GetTotalFileCount");
 fileListPaginationer.registerUpdatePagingCallBack(function () 
 { 
     /* This function will call when paging button clicked or updated.
        Parameters will passed like (clickedPageIndex)
        User dispose real pagination data like file list table...(etc) 
      */
 });
```

JavaScript developers usually say that java script event or request must be run with async,  but i have no idea that i can't know total data count in component initializing time.

Well... maybe show loading... message until request/response total data count will be the way of this problem...
If Possible i want to initialize pagination component in initialize time.
(like window.onload)
(ps: I think the loading message is a little bit burdensome.)

May i have some suggestion about design this pagination component?
I had never designed library or component with async.

Comment: If you can try to put the logic for creating the pagination links in a separate function, say rerender(), and call rerender from the success callback of getTotalDataCount()

Comment: @abhikr Thanks to answering, but  the pagination has no button at first time and it will re rendering when the ajax async httprequest will responded (when the total data count result get).

Comment: Yes, that is what you expect right?

Comment: Uhm.. It's a little bit different. I want to show web page when all components( like a pagination ~~ etc ) are already loaded. But it works with async and javascript always recommend use async instead of sync... So i have no idea about how to do this. Maybe when the page is loaded and showing but the pagination is not completed yet at same time then how should i gonna show to user? a loading splash ?

Comment: A loader or splash until you load the bare minimum data for your UI seems to be the way.

Comment: @abhikr7 Thanks a lot.